# ASP.NET MVC Dynamic Model not being recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use 2 models in 1 view in an ASP.NET MVC application and am trying to use the dynamic model approach as described here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/

This is my controller:

#### Details controller

```
    // GET: Statewides/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            ViewBag.ID = id;
            var today = DateTime.Today;
            var todayAsString = today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            ViewBag.Today = todayAsString;
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Statewide statewide = db.Statewides.Find(id);

            var document = from s in db.Documents
                           where s.Statewide_ID == id
                           select s;

            dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
            mymodel.Statewides = statewide;
            mymodel.Documents = document;

            if (statewide == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(mymodel);
        }
```

And this is a part of my view:

```
@model  dynamic

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
                <h5><strong>COUNTY:</strong> <span class="box-shadow px-3">@Model.Statewide.COUNTY</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-right district">
                <h5><strong>District:</strong>@Model.Statewide.District</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And at the bottom of that page I need to access the Documents model:

```
       <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Doc Type</th>
                <th>Order Date</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (Document document in Model.Documents)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@document.Doc_Type</td>
                    <td>@document.Order_Date</td>
                    <td>@document.Doc_Location</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

Here I get an error on `Document` saying "The type or namespace Document could not be found". I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong as it looks to me like I've done the same thing as the guide.

Here is the full view if you need it, PLEASE NOTE I have not changed a lot of the instances of the retrieving values from the old model that was only Statewide. Please ignore those:

```
@model  dynamic

<!--            CUSTOM CSS          -->
<link href="~/Styles/Documents/DetailsStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--            GOOGLE ICONS          -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<div class="bigContainer">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center topLabel">
        <div class="borderline">
            <h4 class="title"><strong>DETAIL RECORD - RP ROADWAY HISTORY FILE</strong></h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 printButton">
                    <input class="text-left" type="button" onclick="javascript:window.print()" value="Print" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <p class="text-right">
                        <u>Current Date:</u>
                        <script>document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString());</script>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
                <h5><strong>COUNTY:</strong> <span class="box-shadow px-3">@Model.Statewide.COUNTY</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-right district">
                <h5><strong>District:</strong>@Model.Statewide.District</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                <h5><strong>Route No:</strong><span class="box-shadow px-4">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RouteNo)</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h5><strong>Sign System:</strong><span class="box-shadow px-4 sign">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SignSys)</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                <h5><strong>LocalName:</strong></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                <h5 class="box-shadow px-3 localName">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LocalName)</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row suppMethodDuplicate">
            <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                <h5><strong>Supp Des:</strong></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
                <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SuppDes)</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                <h5><strong>Method:</strong></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
                <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Method)</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Duplicate_OK)
                <label class="form-check-label" for="duplicateCheck"><strong>Duplicate OK</strong></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                <h5><strong>Date:</strong></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
                <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ReservedDate)</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                <h5><strong>Original Location:</strong></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
                <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OriginalL)</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                <h5><strong>Original D:</strong></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                <h6>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OriginalD)</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="borderline text-left">
            <h5 class="mb-0"><strong>DOCUMENTS</strong></h5>
        </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Doc Type</th>
                <th>Order Date</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (Document document in Model.Documents)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@document.Doc_Type</td>
                    <td>@document.Order_Date</td>
                    <td>@document.Doc_Location</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>


        <div class="borderline text-left">
            <h5 class="mb-0"><strong>PROJECTS</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <h6 class="text-left">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Projects)</h6>
        <div class="borderline text-left">
            <h5 class="mb-0"><strong>COMMENTS</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <h6 class="text-left">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Comments)</h6>
    </div>

    <p style="margin-top: 20px">
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>

</div>
```

Serge suggested I use view model so I have tried this:

#### ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Roadway_History.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public Statewide Statwide { get; set; }
        public Document Document { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Action

```
// GET: Statewides/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            ViewBag.ID = id;
            var today = DateTime.Today;
            var todayAsString = today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            ViewBag.Today = todayAsString;
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var model = new ViewModel
            {


            Statewide statewide = db.Statewides.Find(id);

            var document = from s in db.Documents
                           where s.Statewide_ID == id
                           select s;
            };
            

            if (statewide == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

But this also doesn't work. I get the errors

`Statewide is a type which is not valid in the given context`and `ViewModel does not contain a definition for statewide`

I belive the action method to be wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Also, using `@model ViewModel` in the view gives the error "The type or namespace ViewModel could not be found"

Comment: Dynamic model in mvc doesn't  make much sense since MVC doesn't have dynamic controls. And  how are going to  benefit using dynamic data and static controls?

Comment: @Serge then what method would you recommend to use 2 models on the same view? I need to access both the Statewides and Documents model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to use two models for one view you can make a viewmodel that contains both of them

```
public class ViewModel 
{
 public  Statewide Statwide {get; set;}
 public  List<Document> Documents {get; set;}

}
```

in the view

```
@model ViewModel
```

action

```
var model = new ViewModel
{
   Statewide= ... your code
   Document=... your code
};
......
return View(model);
```

UPDATE

fix your viewmodel like this

```
 var statewide = db.Statewides.FirstOrDefault (i=> i.Id==id);
 if (statewide == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
 var documents = db.Documents.Where(s=> s.Statewide_ID == id).ToList();

            if (documents == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
          
var model = new ViewModel
            {
            Statewide =statewide, 
            Documents = documents
            };

  return View(model);
```

but you will need to fix model too according to new viewmodel

Comment: I have updated my question to show where I have tried what you suggested. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong in the action?

Comment: Ok now when I run it I get this error ````Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Roadway_History.Models.Document]' to type 'Roadway_History.Models.Document'.```` pointing to the line ````var model = new ViewModel````

Comment: If I try to do ````Document = document```` I get the error ````Cannot implicitly convert type 'type1' to 'type2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)````` So I did this instead  ````Document = (Document)document```` is that ok?

Comment: @GrillOwner69420 I am sorry. c# is case sensitive  what is your document class name is?  Document or document? It is highly recomended to use upper case for class names. This is why I am using Document. but if it is document  fix viewmodel this way  -  public  document Document{get; set;}

Comment: No it is upper case Document.

Comment: If I need to, I can post a new question with all the necessary code and share the link here. I tremendously appreciate your help here.

Comment: @GrillOwner69420 If you are using my code for viewmodel  you should not have any error.  Did you check my code carefull?

Comment: @GrillOwner69420  I fixed you EF queries, they had some bugs . Pls try again.

Comment: Yes that did it. Thank you so much Serge! You're the best.

Comment: @GrillOwner69420 You are welcome. Ask any questions if you still have some problems.

Comment: Wait 1 thing...  the firstOrDefault will only return 1 result correct? There may be more than 1 document that matches the statewideID and I need both of those. I don't believe that ````var document = db.Documents.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Statewide_ID == id);```` will give me an item that I can loop over, which I need to do. Am I correct in this and is there any way I can make this possible?

Comment: @GrillOwner69420 I updated my answer, pls check viewmodel and action.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need but in the action ````Documents = documents```` I get the error ```` Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<Roadway_History.Models.Document> to Roadway_History.Models.Document ````

Comment: @GrillOwner69420 Check viewmodel of the answer too. Viewmodel is changed to public  List<Document> Documents {get; set;}

Comment: I didn't even notice I apologize. That did it. Thank you so so much I've learned a ton about using view models!